# Blender cloth collision not working

Tags: cycles-render-engine, cloth-simulation, collision

[image]

I have been trying to make this effect with my design. But it doesn't work. My object underneath is keep on showing thru the cloth (below image).
[image]

[image]

[image]
I tried joining both of the objects (the heart and the cylinder) and applied collision + applying collision to them separately, but it didn't work.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[here is the link to the tutorial that I followed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gFOJ7ul19AE&t=103s&ab_channel=Ducky3D)

**Update:**

Thanks for the reply, but it still doesn't work. Here is the model.

[image]

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: *"...and applied collision + applying collision to them separately..."* <-- Have you enabled *Collision* in the physics properties tab and then apply the *Collision* modifier in the modifiers tab which was added by the physics? And it's gone? You don't need to apply the *Collision* modifier, just add it. But Blender does this automatically when you enable *Collision* in the physics tab.

Comment: Have you checked the normals/face orientation of the heart and the foil to be sure it's not inside out?